# Drupal 7 #ajax change event prevents other change event handlers on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm building custom form with select element using Drupal 7 Form Api. I'm attaching #ajax callback to it, which will fire on change event.

```
$form['landing']['country'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('landing-country-list')),
    '#validated' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="landing-countries" class="hide">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',    
    '#title' => 'Select country',
    '#ajax' => array(

      'wrapper' => 'landing-cities',

      'callback' => 'get_cities',

      'event' => 'change',

      'effect' => 'none',

      'method' => 'replace'

    ),    
);
```

But the problem is that it prevents custom change function on the same select in js. In this function I want to get selected option value. So this will not fire:

```
$('body').on('change', 'select.landing-country-list', function() {
    optval = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
});
```

This code is in file, which I include in $form:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
    drupal_get_path('module', 'landing') . '/landing.js',
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch before ajax sending you can use :

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
    var val = $('select.landing-country-list').val();
});
```

Otherwise if you want to get value after ajaxcallback :

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr , options) {
          if(typeof options.extraData != 'undefined' && options.extraData['_triggering_element_name'] === 'country'){
// only on ajax event attached to country select
               var val =  $('select.landing-country-list').val();
          }
    });
```